# Numpy savetxt TypeErrror

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to save a 5D array and I'm having this error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "model_3.py", line 53, in
> <module>
>     np.savetxt('../test_set/exp3/X.txt', X_test, delimiter=' ', fmt='%1.12f')   File
> "/home/jasper/.virtualenvs/thesis/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
> line 1160, in savetxt
>     % (str(X.dtype), format)) TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier ('%1.12f %1.12f %1.12f')
```

Comment: `savetxt` is designed to work with a 2d array, e.g. one with shape `(3,5)`..  I get an error if I try to save a `(2,3,5)` array, though not exactly same one as you.  Show `X_test.shape` and `X_test.dtype` so there's no misunderstanding about its form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`savetxt` iterates over the 1st dimension of your array, and for each 'row' tries to do:

```
format % tuple(row)
```

The `format`, which it constructed from your `fmt` and array shape (`X.shape[1]`) is

```
'%1.12f %1.12f %1.12f'
```

If the array is not 2d, then `row` will not be 1d, and this `tuple(row)`  conversion will not match `format`.

`savetxt` is designed for simple 2d arrays (or 1d structured arrays), not 5d ones.